# No information in a variable is being displayed on Django Website

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner in python and I am learning python. I am creating a Website using Django and faced a problem once trying to add information into the django website using for loops in Django HTML. The information from the below **bolded** code is not being displayed, can someone please help me out!

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Language</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Year Published</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {% for course in courses %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{course.name}}</td>
            <td>{{course.language}}</td>
            <td>{{course.cost_in_rupees}}</td>
            <td>{{course.year_published}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

This is the View:-

[image]

This is my code of the `views.py` file:-

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Course



def index(request):
    courses = Course.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {"Courses": courses})
```

Comment: can you add the view?

Comment: Done, Hope you can help me

Comment: I still don't see the view, all I see is the template

Comment: Can you see it now, if not please bear with me I am new to Stack Overflow

Comment: Your context variable is `Courses` but in the template you're using `courses`. Looks like a simple case issue.

Comment: Oh I am so sorry, Thank You So Much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your context variable is `Courses` but in the template you're using `courses`.

So this will resolve it;

```
def index(request):
    courses = Course.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {"courses": courses})
```

Looks like a simple case issue.